# Storing file on a sharepoint location

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, sharepoint

How should I create a file at sharepoint location by c# code.
I am getting the data from webservic and I want to create an excel file for that.

I tried this code :

```
        string path = "http://matrix-ab:7001/matrix/common/Servlet.jsp?service=true&cmd=abcd&sk=gfdgsfdgsfdgsfdgsfdgsdfSEVnR0lWMEsdvfds0&ObjName=";
        string destFilename = @"http://test.net/excel/docs/test.aspx/abc.xlsm";
        System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient();
        WebDownload w = new WebDownload(3600000);
        UTF8Encoding objUTF8 = new UTF8Encoding();
        byte[] data = w.DownloadData(path + value);
        File.WriteAllBytes(destFilename, data);
        w = null;
        objUTF8 = null;
        Console.WriteLine("Completed");
```

Error:

```
URI formats are not supported.
```

I am getting values which I keep on excel. If I keep the path as the local or shared location, then it works, but it does not work on sharepoint location.

Comment: is this code running in sharepoint or where?
Your destination file name is wrong it cannot be a url.
Choose a local path or save the file to a document list.

Comment: @Legends I want to save it to the sharepoint server location.

Comment: I know, the question is, where does the above code run, on the SP Server machine or on another computer/server?

Comment: @Legends On other computer/server